# Angular $http.post google maps Javascript API error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, google-maps

I'm having a problem with Google Maps Javascript API while using Angular JS `$http.post()`, before any other explanation, this is the error:

```
angular.js:13642 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined
        at _.H.toString (js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places:97)
        at e (jquery.min.js:4)
        at dc (jquery.min.js:4)
        at dc (jquery.min.js:4)
        at dc (jquery.min.js:4)
        at dc (jquery.min.js:4)
        at dc (jquery.min.js:4)
        at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
        at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
        at dc (jquery.min.js:4)
```

Which occours here:
**app.js**

```
_sost.validateSost = function(form){
    $http.post(php_data.ajax_url, send_data, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }
    }).success(function(response){
        var data = response.data;
        _sost._posting = false;
        _sost._postresult = data.status;
        if(data.status == 0){
            _sost._inserted = _completed.length;
        }
    }).then(function () {
        _sost.lista = [{}];
    });
}
_sost.addLocation = function (sost) {
    if (sost.luogo && typeof(sost.luogo) == 'object') {
        var google_location = sost.luogo;
        var location_components = google_location.address_components;
        var location_geometry = google_location.geometry.location;
        if (location_components) {
            location_components.forEach(function (item) {
                var _type = item.types[0];
                if (_type == 'administrative_area_level_1') {
                    sost.regione = item.long_name;
                } else if (_type == 'administrative_area_level_2') {
                    sost.provincia = item.long_name;
                } else if (_type == 'administrative_area_level_3') {
                    sost.comune = item.long_name;
                } else if (_type == 'postal_code') {
                    sost.cap = item.short_name;
                } else if (_type == 'route') {
                    sost.indirizzo = item.long_name;
                } else if (_type == 'country') {
                    sost.nazione = item.long_name;
                }
            });
            if (!sost.hasOwnProperty('cap')) {
                sost.cap = null;
            }
            if (!sost.hasOwnProperty('indirizzo')) {
                sost.indirizzo = null;
            }
            sost.location = google_location.formatted_address;
        }
        if (location_geometry) {
            sost.lat = location_geometry.lat();
            sost.lng = location_geometry.lng();
        }
    }
};
```

This is the `HTML` part:

```
<section id="registra-membro" ng-controller="sostenitori as st">
    <form novalidate method="post" name="st_f" id="add-sostenitori" ng-submit="st.validateSost(st_f)" ng-show="!st._posting">
        ...
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" ng-change="st.addLocation(sost)" g-places-autocomplete force-selection="true" ng-model="sost.luogo" name="lu_{{$index}}" class="col-2-3" placeholder="Indirizzo" required/>
    </form>
</section>
```

I'm using the `google.places` module to load Google Maps's autocomplete, and everything works fine, but I can't realize how this error triggers while using `$http.post()`, because there are no `Google Maps API` related functions.

If you need more code please ask, this is really becoming weird, I'm using `jQuery 1.12.4` and `AngularJS 1.5.6`

#### Update

I'm trying to find this error in `Google Maps Javascript API`, and i've found something here:

```
_.H.prototype.toString=function() {
    return"("+this.lat()+", "+this.lng()+")"
}
```

Which is actually the part that is giving me error, but I can't find where it calls this `_.H.prototype.toString` function.
`H` should be the `geometry.location` part, it has methods like `lat` and `lng` which gives location coordinates

#### Another update

I've found which part of my `angular` code triggers that function in `Google Maps API Javascript`, and it's this:

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function (data) {
        if (data === undefined) {
            return data;
        }
        console.log($.param(data));
        return data;
    };
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
});
```

The `$.param(data)` triggers the error, and I guess this is a nice step forward :)

Comment: Have you tried working with JSON.stringify(data) instead of $.param(data) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 1 day of complete stuck, I've solved my problem.
After searching inside `Google Maps API Javascript` for hours, I've discovered that the problem was a `jQuery` function, which is `$.param()`.
I don't know why it triggered the error ( described previously ), but changing it removed my problem, so, this is what I've done.

**app.js**

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function (data) {
        if (data === undefined) {
            return data;
        }
        // !! REMOVED $.param(data)
        return data;
    };
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
});
// Added $httpParamSerializerJQLike in dependencies
$http.post(php_data.ajax_url, $httpParamSerializerJQLike(send_data), {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    }
}).then(function (response) {
    var data = response;
    if (data.hasOwnProperty('status')) {
        _sost._posting = false;
        _sost._postresult = data.status;
        if (data.status == 0) {
            _sost._inserted = _completed.length;
        }
    }
    _sost.lista = [{}];
});
```

So, basically, I've replaced `jQuery.param()` function with another `AngularJS` built-in function, found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike)

Comment: what's important for future readers, please, specify versions that you use, JQuery and Angular

Comment: @KirillSlatin sure, I'll add now to my question :)